# Using a java project in an other java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have 2 java Projects, i want to use one in the other, i've tried to export the one which i want to  use it as jar file and i've added it in the build path of the other , but when i excute ,this exception is raised "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" .
help please (i WANT  TO CONSERVE THIS 2 PROJECTS SEPARATE)!

Comment: please post the full stack trace. questions like these are a magnet for downvotes. but, i'll overlook it this time.

Comment: That exception could mean many things a couple of which are class cannot be found or incompatible compiler versions being used. Full stack trace and project structure should help identify the issue.

Comment: You're missing a dependency somewhere.

Comment: Are you getting that error when you run the project in eclipse, or when you run the project outside of eclipse?

Comment: when i run the project in  eclipse

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Is it because this is a perfect question or there is a duplicate overlooked?

Comment: Problem solved thanks for all who try  to  help me
and a  special thanks for  the one who make a downvote !

Answer (score 2):

You can add the project as a dependency from the build path configuration.

Comment: Thx  the  problem is solved but with jar file.the problem was  caused by the  lack  of  some dependency .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the first project as main project, and the second as a dependency, you can mark the second project as "Is Library" in this case you can import the second project and use the classes in the main project

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError exception happens on a Foo.class when the class loader tries to load that class (not to be confused with ClassNotFoundException, which means, the class was not found). Usually happens when a static member can not be created for Foo.class, i.e.

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
```

and you don't have a dependency to create the logger instance.
The confusing part is the NoClassDefFoundError blaming the Foo.class and not the logger Class/dependency.